# ios saving and retrieving NSNumber from NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I've searched but I can't find a good explanation as to why I'm still not getting the right value from my saved Integer.

This is how I saved my event Id.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger:eventSelected.eventId forKey:@"currentEvent"];
```

This is how I'm trying to retrieve it.

```
NSLog(@"user dfault %@", [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentEvent"] unsignedIntegerValue]]);
```

I'm gettin gthis.

> user dfault 123581200

Also, to note, event if I did **intValue** instead of **unsignedIntegerValue** , it would still give me a random id number. was wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// Convert your value to IntegerValue and Save it
[prefs setInteger:[eventSelected.eventId integerValue] forKey:@"currentEvent"];
// Dont forget to synchronize UserDefaults
[prefs synchronize];

// To Access this value
NSLog(@"%d",[prefs integerForKey:@"currentEvent"]);
```

Comment: Thanks @NSPratik, one can save `NSNumber` object directly to `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this code `NSLog(@"user dfault %@", [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentEvent"] unsignedIntegerValue]]);`

Use this

```
NSLog(@"user dfault %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  integerForKey:@"currentEvent"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the integer you should use below function:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  integerForKey:@"currentEvent"];
```

when you ask for objectForKey, it box it first and then return the object. Posting intValue will convert the address of that object into integer. Hence each time you will receive different number.

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumber` give a pointer value, not integer value.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSNumber *number;
```

store:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:number forKey:@"Number"];
```

retrieving:

```
number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Number"]];
```